# How to display default(English) keypad in android app?

Tags: android

Please let me know how to display the default(English) keypad in android app even when the user changes the device language to urdu/chinese/hindi.

please suggest me some ideas to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

if you set "edittextview in your app, android automatically wake up default keypad

Comment: Hi MSS,Thanks for your reply. But my problem is.                          I have one edit text in my app when ever user changes language in device settings and if the user tries to enter input in edittext box,the keypad shows the changed language. But i need to restrict only english input for edit text.